# SSIS Importing Odd Text Files

Tags: text, import, ssis

Trying to import the below Text Files

[image: BRS]

Trying to understand what the best option is, I need the Bill Run ID from Line 3 column 2 and then all of the details from line 5 on wards which is 14 columns wide, and as I am pretty new to this trying to follow the best route

Thanks
Geoff

Answer (score 2):

SSIS is fantastic for importing tabular files. You have a report/multi-format file which are common in mainframe/EDI/EHR systems but not supported natively in SSIS.

In this easier case, I'd create an SSIS package with a Script Task that opens the file and reads out the Bill Run ID from line 3 and pushes that into an SSIS Variable. That should be like 5 lines of C#.

Then, define your Flat File Connection manager such that it skips the first 3 rows and has column names defined. Use that in a data flow task with a Flat File Source and then have a Derived Column transformation in there that injects the Bill run id variable into the data flow.

Answer (score 1):

Bill is right, this is pretty easy for a combo of C# and SSIS. However, I would do a little bit more in C# than Bill would.

Here's my answer...

Use script component (Source).
Make sure to define your Output columns and cast your data types (or treat them all as strings and cast in your data flow).

Note: Arrays are base 0, so your second column is 1.

```
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("[filepath]");

    int lineCt = 0;
    int RunID;
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        lineCt++;
        if (lineCt == 3)
        {
            string[] pieces = line.Split(',');
            RunID = Int32.Parse(pieces[1]);
        }

        if (lineCt >= 5)
        {
            string[] split = line.Split(',');
            //Write out your columns to data flow
            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            Output0Buffer.RunID = RunID;
            Output0Buffer.Col1 = split[0];
            ...
            Output0Buffer.Col14 = split[13];
        }

    }
```